# How do i control the Slidetoggle function in jquery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Hi Sorry for this noob question but here goes...i have a working slidetoggle on a test site of mine, however when i click the "slide" button, i would like that button to change to "close"..and then change back to "slide" when you click close...again sorry for the newbie question.. heres my code..

```
<script>
/*#boxmove is my button*/
/*.box1 is my sliding panel*/

 $('#boxmove').click(function() {
 $('.box1').slideToggle('slow', function(showOrHide) {

});
});
</script>
```

i know if i add the following i can get it to show the close on click...but i dont know how to "toggle" that text (maybe within a if/else statment?)...

```
<script>
$('#boxmove').click(function() {
$('.box1').slideToggle('slow', function(showOrHide) {
document.getElementById('boxmove').innerHTML = 'close';          
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you are using jQuery use it completely. To access element by id you can use id  selector `$('#elementId')`.

Inside the `slideToggle` callback you can use `text` jQuery method to set the text of the button conditionally. I am using `is` jQuery method to check if the box is visible or not and based on that setting the text of the button.

```
$('#boxmove').click(function() {
      $('.box1').slideToggle('slow', function(showOrHide) {
          $('#boxmove').text($(this).is(':visible')? 'slide' : 'close');          
      });
});
```